# Convert list of np.int64 to list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to convert list of np.int64 values to string values inside a pandas series.

Column values look like this:

```
1. [0000, 3321, 76463, 858505,...]
2. [00300, 2421, 769063, 853205,...]
3. [0000, 89321, 216463, 85899,...]
...
```

Tried iterating using a loop -

```
for i in df['col']:
    for j in i:
        j = str(j)
```

And tried list comprehension, but none of that worked.
`df['col'][i][j]` would still be a np.int64.

Ideally, I want to 'unpack' all values to a sequence of strings, so the answer would look like:

```
'0000' , '3321', '76463', '858505'...
'00300', '2421', '769063', '853205'...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Strategy: Create a new data structure to populate with values from the old one. Might this help?

```
stringData = [] #New empty structre for the string data.
for i in range(len(df['col'])): #Iterate through each column
    stringData.append[] #Append a new column to the new structure
    for j in df['col'][i]: #Iterate through each item in each column
        stringData[i].append(str(j)) # Append a new item to the new column
```

Comment: stringData.append([])